# Multiple string match in regex Python

Tags: python, regex

I want to find a match in string for the following pattern (field1)(field2)(field3)

field 1 can be either 'alpha' or 'beta' or 'gamma'
field 2 is any number(can be whole number or decimal)
field 3 is 'dollar' or 'sky' or 'eagle' or 'may'

Input string1 : "There is a string which contains alpha 2 sky as a part of it"
Output1: alpha 2 sky

Input string2 : "This sentence contains a pattern beta 10.2 eagle"
Output2: beta 10.2 eagle

I'm trying the following code but it's not flexible to include the multiple string matches together.
value = " This sentence contains a pattern beta 10.2 eagle"

```
match = re.findall("beta \d.* dollar", value)
```

Comment: `match = re.search("[beta | alpha | gamma]* \d.* [dollar | sky | eagle | may]*", value)` something like this ?

Comment: @AkshayJain isn't `[...]` means character set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the following regex to collect all the relevant fields

- `(alpha|beta|gamma)` : capture group - alternation with one of this words
- `\s+` : follow by 1+ whitespaces
- `(` : capture group

  - `\d+` : 1+ digits, follow by
  - `(?:\.\d+)?` :  (an optional) non-capturing group - literal '.' follow by 1+ digits
- `)` : close capture group
- `\s+` : follow by 1+ whitespaces
- `(dollar|sky|eagle|may)` : capture group - alternation with one of this words

```py
import re
regex = r'(alpha|beta|gamma)\s+(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s+(dollar|sky|eagle|may)'

s = '''
There is a string which contains alpha 2 sky as a part of it
This sentence contains a pattern beta 10.2 eagle
'''

match = re.finditer(regex, s)

for m in match:
     print(m.group(0))

# alpha 2 sky
# beta 10.2 eagle
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This works ! Would be great if you could explain this, as I'm new to regex.